# Confused by output of keras.text.preprocessing.one_hot

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have some text data that I'd like to convert to one hot vectors:

```py
from keras.preprocessing import text

s = 'wow this is such a thing'
vocab = set(s.split())
text.one_hot(s, round(len(vocab)*1.3))
```

This returns `[2, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7]` but my string does not contain any repeated words. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source code of the function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6701f27afa62712b34a17d4b0ff879156b0c7937/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L41): It clearly states that:

> This is a wrapper to the `hashing_trick` function using `hash` as the
> hashing function; unicity of word to index mapping non-guaranteed.

Since in hashing there is a chance to getting assigned to same index, as your example. You can try to increase the size of `vocab` if you want more uniqueness.

Comment: Amen, interesting. I just wrote my own wrapper instead to prevent collisions. Thanks!